# Parsing using GDataXML with XPATH

Tags: ios, xpath, gdataxml

I have an XML file with multiple entry nodes:

```
<entry>
    <published>2013-12-19T13:30:20-05:00</published>
    <title>This is a title</title>
    <content type="html">This is the content</content>
    <author>
        <name>Valentina</name>
    </author>
</entry>
```

I am trying to parse it using XPath(for learning purpose) but I can't seem to make it work. I have the following code:

```
        NSData* xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
        GDataXMLDocument *document = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil];

        NSArray* entries = [document.rootElement elementsForName:@"entry"];
        for(GDataXMLElement* element in entries)
        {
            published = [element nodesForXPath:@"/entry/published" error:nil][0];
        }
```

I always get an error with `index 0 beyond bounds for empty array` when trying to get the `published` node text. I tried different things but can't figure it out what is the correct way.
Entries array contains 10 entry nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath is evaluated from the current context, which already is an `<entry/>` element. Change the XPath expression to `./published` or even just `published`.

```
published = [element nodesForXPath:@"published" error:nil][0];
```

But why use XPath at all if you just want to query a child node?

```
published = [element elementsForName:@"published"][0];
```